# ajax call link to new page not returning new page

Tags: ajax, grails

I have this ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "${createLink(controller:'MyController', action:'downloadFile') } target=\"_blank\" ",
       data: {'names':JSON.stringify(names)},
       dataType: 'json'
});
```

Which calls this controller method, which works

```
def downloadFile =
{
    List<JSON> Mynames = JSON.parse(params.names)
    Mynames.each{println "MY ID is: $it"}

    [Mynames:Mynames]
}
```

It prints out the MY ID Is Lines, but it doesn't render the downloadFile View which is this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    test
   </body>
</html>
```

However, it is not rendering it.  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take some time to do some reading on Ajax and what it is used for and how it works.  You have a fundamental misunderstanding.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "${createLink(controller:'MyController', action:'downloadFile') } target=\"_blank\" ",
       data: {'names':JSON.stringify(names)},
       dataType: 'json'
});
```

The above code submits a request to your controller.  Here's the key point; **it does not refresh your page or put any data on your page.  It only returns data to you in JavaScript.**

You're controller isn't even returning the correct response based on your $.ajax() functions `dataType` parameter.  The `dataType` property tells the $.ajax() function what kind of data to expect as the response.

[jQuery $.ajax() docco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you need to render HTML as a response to your ajax request, the easiest way is to use the [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

There are a few other ways but for the sake of keeping things simple for you I won't go into them here.  Seriously though, not trying to be rude, but I've read some of your other questions.  You really need to get a better understanding of the tools you're using.

Comment: Thanks!  New to Web development and been thrown into it rather quickly and still learning.  Appreciate the time you took to write a detailed and personal answer.